# Spring boot app startup failure

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-boot, entitymanager

My Spring boot app is failing to start with the following message in the console.

```
/\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.0.RELEASE)

2018-03-27 13:42:13.816  INFO 2516 --- [           main] com.bijit.BootTestApplication            : Starting BootTestApplication on INENBIRINBL2C with PID 2516 (started by birinb in C:\Users\birinb\workspace\Spring Projects1\BootTest)
2018-03-27 13:42:13.818  INFO 2516 --- [           main] com.bijit.BootTestApplication            : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-03-27 13:42:13.851  INFO 2516 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@184cf7cf: startup date [Tue Mar 27 13:42:13 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-03-27 13:42:14.508  INFO 2516 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-03-27 13:42:14.524  INFO 2516 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-03-27 13:42:14.525  INFO 2516 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.28
2018-03-27 13:42:14.529  INFO 2516 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;C:\windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_131/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_131/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_131/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files\avs\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\RSA SecurID Token Common;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\EMC\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin;C:\Users\birinb\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\birinb\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\birinb\Software\eclipse;;.]
2018-03-27 13:42:14.617  INFO 2516 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-03-27 13:42:14.617  INFO 2516 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 768 ms
2018-03-27 13:42:14.656  INFO 2516 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-03-27 13:42:14.690  WARN 2516 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'service'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerDaoImpl': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available
2018-03-27 13:42:14.692  INFO 2516 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-03-27 13:42:14.699  WARN 2516 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
 com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:43)
2018-03-27 13:42:14.705  INFO 2516 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-03-27 13:42:14.797 ERROR 2516 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field dao in com.bijit.service.CustomerServiceImpl required a bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
```

-Saying entity manager bean not found in DaoImpl class, but I have defined it there.

```
package com.bijit.dao;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.bijit.entity.Customer;

@Repository
@Transactional 
public class CustomerDaoImpl implements CustomerDao {

    @PersistenceContext
     EntityManager em;

    public List<Customer> findAll(){
        TypedQuery<Customer> query  =em.createQuery("Select c from customer c", Customer.class);
        return query.getResultList();

    }

    public Customer findById(Long id){
        return em.find(Customer.class, id);
    }

    public void deleteCustomer(Customer customer){
        em.remove(customer);
        }

    public void deleteById(Long id){
        Customer customer = findById(id);
        em.remove(customer);
    }

    public void saveCustomer(Customer customer){

        if(customer.getId()==null){
            em.persist(customer);
        }
        else{
            em.merge(customer);
        }
    }


}
```

Please help me out. Can't understand what the issue is. Tried using @Autowired also in place of @PersistanceContext still it's not working.

Comment: Please have a look on : [Injecting EntityManager Vs. EntityManagerFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310087/injecting-entitymanager-vs-entitymanagerfactory). BTW you say "_Saying entity manager bean not found_", but it is said `EntityManagerFactory` not found, it's not the same ;)

Comment: please also share the `@SpringBootApplication` class

Answer (score 2):

It is saying **no bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' that could not be found**

And in your class you are using - javax.persistence.EntityManager;

Is your build clean?

**UPDATE**

Try adding:-

```
@Bean
public LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean em =
    new LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    return em;
}
```

is your application spring-boot application? if yes then you should skip above bean.

do you have the following dependency in your project:-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And in your application.properties you may need to add db details something like this:-

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:amqp-demo;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Most of the properties here will vary as per your database

I was using H2 db so things are more specific to those

Comment: Ya, my build is clean. Since I am using javax.persistence.EntityManager, then why it's asking for EntityManagerFactory?

Comment: are you autowiring the classes, i.e repository and service classes correctly?

Comment: Yes, it's a spring boot project. All the autowiring are done correctly.

Comment: I have those data-source declarations in my application.properties.

Comment: please also share the `@SpringBootApplication` class

Answer (score 0):

It says that `javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory` cannot be found. This class comes from JPA. Have you included a JPA provider in your project?

Comment: Yes, i have included that dependency.

Comment: I have added my pom.xml file for reference

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.bijit</groupId>
    <artifactId>RANDOM</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>BootTest</name>
    <description>boot test</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Service class-

```
package com.bijit.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.bijit.dao.CustomerDao;
import com.bijit.entity.Customer;

@Service
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {

    @Autowired
    public CustomerDao dao;

    public List<Customer> getCustomers(){
        return dao.findAll();
    }

    public Customer getCustomer(Long id){
        return dao.findById(id);
    }

    public void deleteCustomer(Long id){
        dao.deleteById(id);
    }

    public void saveCustomer(Customer customer){
        dao.saveCustomer(customer);
    }
}

package com.bijit;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class BootTestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BootTestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following bean in your Application class

```
@Bean
public SessionFactory sessionFactory(@Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory emf) {
         return emf.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
}
```

Then autowire sessionFactory in your Dao as follows:

```
@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

Now you can use sessions from this sessionFactory for accessing your DB

Comment: It's a spring boot app, I think it doesn't require separate bean definition. And I want to use entity manager for JPA implementation, not session factory which is used in Hibernate.